# Converting all text files with multiple encodings in a directory into a utf-8 encoded text files

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I am new starter in Python and, in general, in coding. So any help is greatly appreciated.

I have more than 3000 text files in a single directory with multiple encodings. And I need to convert them into a single encoding (e.g. utf8) for further NLP work. When I checked the type of these files using shell, I identified the following encodings:

```
Algol 68 source text, ISO-8859 text, with very long lines
Algol 68 source text, Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines
Algol 68 source text, Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines
Algol 68 source text, Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines, with LF, NEL line terminators
ASCII text
ASCII text, with very long lines
data
diff output text, ASCII text
ISO-8859 text, with very long lines
ISO-8859 text, with very long lines, with LF, NEL line terminators
Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines
Non-ISO extended-ASCII text
Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines
Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines, with LF, NEL line terminators
UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

Any ideas how to convert text files with the above mentioned encodings into text files with a utf-8 encoding?

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem like you.
I used two steps to solve this problem.

code is below:

```
import os, sys, codecs
import chardet
```

First, using chardet package to identify the coding of text.

```
for text in os.listdir(path):
    txtPATH = os.path.join(path, text)
    txtPATH=str(txtPATH)
    

    f = open(txtPATH, 'rb')
    data = f.read()
    f_charInfo = chardet.detect(data)
    coding2=f_charInfo['encoding']
    coding=str(coding2)
    print(coding)
    data = f.read()
```

Second, if coding of text is not utf-8, rewrite the text as utf-8 encoding to the directory.

```
        if not re.match(r'.*\.utf-8$', coding, re.IGNORECASE): 
        print(txtPATH)
        print(coding)

        with codecs.open(txtPATH, "r", coding) as sourceFile:
            contents = sourceFile.read()
            
            
            with codecs.open(txtPATH, "w", "utf-8") as targetFile:              
                targetFile.write(contents)
```

Hope this can help! Thanks